# Redirecting to @timecard results in 'no route matches [PATCH] "/timecards"

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Can't figure out this routing problem: I redirect from my update controller action to the modified @timecard, and get the following error: No route matches [PATCH] "/timecards"

Why does rails try to redirect using PATCH and to timecards#index?

Is that not how I redirect to the recently edited @timecard?

In **timecards_controller.rb**:

```
  def edit
    @timecard = Timecard.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @timecard = Timecard.find(params[:id])
    @timecard.update_attributes!(timecard_params)
    redirect_to @timecard
  end
```

Output of **rake routes**:

```
$ rake routes
                      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                 Controller#Action
   timecard_timecard_entries GET    /timecards/:timecard_id/timecard_entries(.:format)          timecard_entries#index
                             POST   /timecards/:timecard_id/timecard_entries(.:format)          timecard_entries#create
 new_timecard_timecard_entry GET    /timecards/:timecard_id/timecard_entries/new(.:format)      timecard_entries#new
edit_timecard_timecard_entry GET    /timecards/:timecard_id/timecard_entries/:id/edit(.:format) timecard_entries#edit
     timecard_timecard_entry GET    /timecards/:timecard_id/timecard_entries/:id(.:format)      timecard_entries#show
                             PATCH  /timecards/:timecard_id/timecard_entries/:id(.:format)      timecard_entries#update
                             PUT    /timecards/:timecard_id/timecard_entries/:id(.:format)      timecard_entries#update
                             DELETE /timecards/:timecard_id/timecard_entries/:id(.:format)      timecard_entries#destroy
                   timecards GET    /timecards(.:format)                                        timecards#index
                             POST   /timecards(.:format)                                        timecards#create
                new_timecard GET    /timecards/new(.:format)                                    timecards#new
               edit_timecard GET    /timecards/:id/edit(.:format)                               timecards#edit
                    timecard GET    /timecards/:id(.:format)                                    timecards#show
                             PATCH  /timecards/:id(.:format)                                    timecards#update
                             PUT    /timecards/:id(.:format)                                    timecards#update
                             DELETE /timecards/:id(.:format)                                    timecards#destroy
                        root GET    /                                                           timecards#index
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was naturally in the view. Thanks to @sircapsalot for pointing me to the log, which indicated that the incorrect route was indeed being called (from an incorrect link in the view).

Answer (score 1):

When you call `redirect_to` you should specify a path.. not necessarily the object itself.

Try,

```
def update
  @timecard = Timecard.find(params[:id])
  @timecard.update_attributes!(timecard_params)
  redirect_to timecard_path(@timecard)
end
```

Comment: Same **Routing Error** page saying: No route matches [PATCH] "/timecards" :(

Comment: really? because `timecard_path` matches the GET route of the timecard.. the problem must be happening at `@timecard.update_attributes!` can you confirm whether or not the timecard updates?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the log... The update action doesn't seem to get called. The edit action is called:
`Started GET "/timecards/3/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-05 18:53:24 +0300`
But the update action is not:
`Started PATCH "/timecards" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-05 18:53:36 +0300`